# Rails gem to add view content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

since often I'm comparing production and development website output, it happens sometimes I try to see latest development edits on the live website (just because they're equal, I don't see the URLbar address) and I lose minutes before to realize I was just looking at the production website.

So I'm willing to create a Rails3 Gem that has to be installed under the "development" group, that automatically adds some output to all views (for example a warning message "DEVELOPMENT MODE" or something like that, and maybe add at the bottom some debug info about the current page).

I've realized I could do this by creating some view helper, returning `nil` if the environment is "production", but it would require to install the gem globally to make it find the view helper also on a production server.

So I'm just trying to figure out if there's another way less intrusive to add such content. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

We used something like below for same purpose. You can place this code on layout view. It looks for client ip address, compare it with pre-configured ip addresses stored 
in config file, if match than show red color bar at the top of the page.

Bit hacky but it work for us.

```
<% if Rails.env.production? and request.remote_ip == ip_address_from_config %>
<div class="heavy-red">
  WARNING! Production Url
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better (and easier to maintain) just checking if the env is `development` and display a Development url? Just curious to know if your solution come after some issue you had doing it.

Comment: Above condition to alert develper & QA makes more sense to us. See red bar at the top automatically make us cautious when we hit production server from our office. We are also exploring to create a firefox (our default development browser) extension instead, which will show red ribbon if developer/qa hit production instance. But for now we are fine with the current implementation.